# Using C++ iterators to access element

Tags: c++, list, iterator

Here is the code to my main method, it should be obvious what i'm trying to do with trying to get the iterator to access an element by name

```
#include <iostream>
#include <list>
#include "PC.h"
#include "SunServer.h"

using namespace std;

int main(){
    PC mypc1("John", "645.22.55.34", 128, "admin");
    PC mypc2("Mike", "645.22.55.34", 128, "admin");
    PC mypc3("Rick", "645.22.55.34", 128, "admin");
    PC mypc4("Bill", "645.22.55.34", 128, "admin");

    list<PC> my_group;

    my_group.push_front(mypc1);
    my_group.push_front(mypc2);
    my_group.push_front(mypc3);
    my_group.push_front(mypc4);
    list<PC>::iterator curr = my_group.begin();

    while (curr != mypc2){
        // do something
    }

}
```

Now obviously it doesn't work, but is there something I can do that would be equivalent to this? Thank you

Comment: Do you increment your iterator inside while {} ? Do like this: `++curr`

Comment: yes that is what I would be doing, the problem is with the (curr != mypc2), it wont except being compared to an object, it wants to be compared to a location in the list, such as (curr != my_group.end())

Answer (score 5):

That's because `curr` is an iterator, and you need something that is a `PC` to compare against. To get a reference to what the iterator is pointing to, you just have to dereference it (just as if it were a pointer, not a coincidence):

```
while (*curr != mypc2) {
```

I'm not sure what you're planning on doing within the loop, but if what you want is just to find the `mypc2`, you can use [`std::find`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find):

```
std::list<PC>::iterator it = std::find(my_group.begin(),
                                       my_group.end(),
                                       mypc2);
```

Comment: sounds like a solid idea, ill be sure to try it, thanks I did not know that "find" was a thing

Comment: @HunterTipton, I recommend reading through [this reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm) and seeing what other algorithms there are. I also recommend `std::vector` unless you have a good reason not to use it.

Comment: Well I have to be able to add and delete at any point in the container, which to my knowledge a vector cannot do

Comment: @HunterTipton It definitely can. It's just `O(N)`, whereas `list` would be `O(1)`.

Comment: also @Barry I attempted to use the find algorithm and recieved this error "error C2678: binary '==' : no operator found which takes a left-hand operand of type 'PC' ", I did try this after including <algorithm> and it did not help

Comment: @HunterTipton Your `PC` class does not have `operator==` defined. You'll have to add that.

Comment: @Hunter: Also, note `find_if`.